# Image styles are not created inside the styles directory

Tags: 9, cdn

I don't know if this is a Drupal CDN module issue. I have been trying to fix this issue for a few days now but I still have no luck.
When I upload an image to my Drupal 9.5 I can see it's been uploaded to one location:
`public:///styles/large/public/banner/10712751_0.jpeg`

I also have some image styles for the same image. I do understand the image styles make the images when someone refers to it, but, in my case now even when I try to load the image style images, those images won't get created under the image style directories. For an example the below locations don't have my physical file created there.

`public:///styles/landing_page_banner_desktop/public/banner/10712751_0.jpeg public:///styles/landing_page_banner_tablet/public/banner/10712751_0.jpeg public:///styles/landing_page_banner_mobile/public/banner/10712751_0.jpeg`

So as a result, I don't see my image URL path has the `/cdn/ff` URL string because the below [condition](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/cdn/-/blob/4.x/src/File/FileUrlGenerator.php#L158) fails since file_exists($absolute_file_path) returns false always since the file is not available.

```
// When farfuture is enabled, rewrite the file URL to let Drupal serve the
// file with optimal headers. Only possible if the file exists.
if ($this->settings->farfutureIsEnabled() && file_exists($absolute_file_path)) {
```

In other words, I'm expecting my image URLs to be like below:

`//assets.company.docksal.site/cdn/ff/Tf5y0t9SVU297c3X_X_YxeMqhvfYFvO3TvLzpBPJzrU/1683669896/public/styles/landing_page_banner_tablet/public/banner/etienne-boulanger-iYcuJQaVTvg.jpg?itok=SJDfT19y`

But I endup getting URL like this (Not with the `/cdn/ff` string)

`//assets.company.docksal.site/sites/default/files/styles/landing_page_banner_tablet/public/banner/10712751_0.jpeg?itok=MKyWYIT3`

In the files browser(`/admin/content/files`) in Drupal (see the attached screen), I can see the original image uploaded and has the correct CDN URL. I'm really not sure why it's not able to upload the files for image style images and generate the CDN URL

What could be the reason for this ?. Could you please help me with this ?.

I have setup my file permissions according to this article [here](https://www.singlemindconsulting.com/blog/fixing-permissions-on-the-files-directory-in-drupal/)

Thanks in advance for looking into this.